# $_POST max array size

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a really big form with >1000 Elements. They are already nested inside the form html structure

```
                {foreach from=$result item=item}
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.receiver.name}" name="item[{$item.id}][receiver][name]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.receiver.account_number}" name="item[{$item.id}][receiver][account_number]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.receiver.bank_code}" name="item[{$item.id}][receiver][bank_code]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.amount}" name="item[{$item.id}][amount]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.usage.first}" name="item[{$item.id}][usage][first]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="{$item.usage.second}" name="item[{$item.id}][usage][second]" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="Yourdelivery GmbH" name="item[{$item.id}][usage][third]" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="item[{$item.id}][import]" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {/foreach}
```

It is to create a DATAUS file for mass bank transactions. But after reaching more than 1000 rows no more elements are added to the $_POST array and the debugger shows the following element count.

[image: Xdebug Output]

I already added max_post_size to 100M for testing, but nothing helped.

Comment: have you got Suhosin installed on this server? Run `php -i | grep -i 'Suhosin'` on the command line to find out. See [`suhosin.post.max_vars`](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_vars) and [`suhosin.post.max_array_index_length`](suhosin.post.max_array_index_length).

Comment: Does [this suggestion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#101755) help?

Comment: had similar problem when i had to simulate a MYSQL consol... i used $_SESSION vars and i could pass long strings (over 1k rows) without problems.

Comment: yes the server ist protecte by Suhosin. I try to fix that max_array_index_length variable

Comment: have added suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 100000 to php.ini but did not help

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try changing [`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) as well. More information: [PHP max_input_vars and big forms](http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/).

Comment: Link to more information is helpful and solved my problem. One little tip: at OS X Mountain Lion php.ini file location is **/private/etc/php.ini**. I have found using **php --ini** command.

Comment: just saved my whole day !

Comment: I have updated max_input_vars = 5000 but nothing is reflecting on my form update.

Comment: This answer is very useful, I've linked it here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63169511/11787139