# What can cause $_POST data to be incomplete

Tags: php, forms, apache, http-post

I have a simple basic HTML form with about 1500 fields. 500 rows have text entries. When form is submitted, `$_POST` contains only about 130 entries of those 500 rows. `post_max_size` is high, so it's not that. You can see the barebone sample here:

http://www.dadilja.rs/test.php

If you check the source after submit, you will see that the `$_POST` data contains entries only until letter F.

So I'm figuring it's some server setting, since there's only HTML on the page, and the behaviour is the same on two different servers - probably some generic setting. If you check the Web console, and inspect Request Body, you will see that the form submits all the data. Any ideas?

Comment: A "simple" HTML form with about 1500 fields is something of an oxymoron

Comment: simplicity is the opposite of complexity. this form is not complex, it is long

Comment: If I see a form with that many fields, I leave that website alone

Comment: that's from admin page, manufacturer attribute values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your php.ini `max_input_vars`. Default is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), check [this](http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/) as well for more info. Source - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807100/post-max-array-size/12667018#12667018).

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.