# Passing Array via jQuerys $.post reduces positions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I can't find any suitable answeres so I ask a new question.

I am working on a bigger webapplication. Now in one Part of the app I collect data from an existing table (`<table class="myContent">...</table>`) with jQuery. Code doesn't matters at this point.

What happens is, I create a Array with content in it and it works fine. Content looks like

```
Array
(
[artikel] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 602145-69430
                [name] => Legraphic 2 Top
                [farbe] => Cashmere Blue mix
                [menge] => 0
                [epreis] => 25.95
                [gpreis] => 0.00
                [uvp] => 64.90
                [grt1] => XS
                [grt2] => S
                [grt3] => M
                [grt4] => L
                [grt5] => XL
                [grt6] => XXL
                [grt7] => 0
                [grt8] => 0
                [grt9] => 0
                [grt10] => 0
                [grt11] => 0
                [grt12] => 0
                [gr1] => 
                [gr2] => 
                [gr3] => 
                [gr4] => 
                [gr5] => 
                [gr6] => 
                [gr7] => 
                [gr8] => 
                [gr9] => 
                [gr10] => 
                [gr11] => 
                [gr12] => 
                [ldate] => LD: 01.02.2015 - 28.02.2015
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 602145-60430
                [name] => Legraphic 2 Top
                [farbe] => Cashmere Blue
                [menge] => 0
                [epreis] => 25.95
                [gpreis] => 0.00
                [uvp] => 64.90
                [grt1] => XS
                [grt2] => S
                [grt3] => M
                [grt4] => L
                [grt5] => XL
                [grt6] => XXL
                [grt7] => 0
                [grt8] => 0
                [grt9] => 0
                [grt10] => 0
                [grt11] => 0
                [grt12] => 0
                [gr1] => 
                [gr2] => 
                [gr3] => 
                [gr4] => 
                [gr5] => 
                [gr6] => 
                [gr7] => 
                [gr8] => 
                [gr9] => 
                [gr10] => 
                [gr11] => 
                [gr12] => 
                [ldate] => LD: 01.02.2015 - 28.02.2015
            )
```

and so on. Now after creating this array, I send it like

```
$.post('php/_includes/_ajaxIncludes/ajax.inc.container.php', 
        {
            section:    'save',
            data:       myArray

        });
```

I call `ajax.inc.container.php` and in that file I include a file named `save.php`. I can switch the inc-file by changing the section-parameter.

**Now here is the issue:**

The created array has eg. 40 positions (or even more) in `artikel` (I did `console.log(myArray);` right before `$.post`) but if I `print_r($_POST['data']['artikel']);` in php, I only get 31 positions and the last position isn't even completed. Looks like

```
[31] => Array
            (
                [id] => 602147-69430
                [name] => Leblock 1 Blouse
                [farbe] => Cashmere Blue mix
                [menge] => 0
                [epreis] => 35.95
                [gpreis] => 0.00
                [uvp] => 89.90
            )
```

anyone know why this can happen ?

**Additional informations:**

> post_max_size  64M

**EDIT**

Obviously the failure comes from jquery.

If I add `.done()` and `.fail()` to `$.post()` and return the response `console.log(response);` he goes into `fail()` if there are more than 30 positions.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, not at all. I don't know how to recive error from php when using ajax/jquery. But i guess there would be non because actually he does the post but not to 100% :)

Comment: Maybe you hit the limit of input vars. Could you tell us your settings regarding the number of post variables that can be sent? See here what I'm talking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807100/post-max-array-size

Comment: I can't give you a exact answer. but.. Did you receive same amount of element in each post? I mean did you receive 31 element all the time? if so probably specific element (i.e 31 st) may contain malformed data. so rearrange items and try again.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna yes its always 31 elements and it doesn't matters what data i take, even its 100 times the same data it stop at 31 and 31 is also never completed. I already tested this

Comment: @MarvinSaldinger actually i don't have any input fields :) I'm collecting this from a but like i sayed, that's not the problem. I i print befor using post, i get 40 elemtes or even more as expected.

Comment: @Dwza yeah, but the web server has a limit. It doesnt matter there are no input fields the data is still sent the same way.

Comment: i checked the size, its 64M guess this should be enough. Shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Dwza what about this variable: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: @MarvinSaldinger no, that's not it :) I could enclose the failure a lil bit, see my edit in my post.

Comment: could you please provide us the data being sent to the server, by inspecting the request in ***network/console*** tab in developer tools? I agree with @MarvinSaldinger, that your are exceeding the post var limit.

Comment: obviously i do exeed the limit. I am trying to change it but its not as easy as it sounds :) If I tested it, I will accept the answere of @MarvinSaldinger :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you receive only 31 complete array elements and the 32nd element has only 7 items.
Each element has 32 items.

31 x 32 = 992

992 + 7 = 999

The default for max_input_vars is 1000.
Maybe I missed one...

Try increasing max_input_vars to 2000 and see if anything changes.

Comment: this looks good and sounds plausible but adding informations to .htaccess results a internal server error :) but this COULD be the problem :)

Comment: omg, you saved my life... or something like this :) at least a lot of gray cells are saved ^^ added new limit to my php.ini on my server and it really solved it. Thought my code is so bad and wasted at least 24h active codingtime + 20 min for writing this post :) Thx alot.

Answer (score 0):

You post data as a raw array. Instead of try to parse JSON object as a string. for eg:

```
$.post('php/_includes/_ajaxIncludes/ajax.inc.container.php', 
    {
        section:    'save',
        data:       JSON.stringify(myArray)

    });
```

Then parse this string to json object. I know this is not the answer for your question but this may help you.

Comment: I am passing it as object filled with arrays. One array is called artikel. But for debugging i only pass it as raw array. Has the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the Array in PHP use `serialize()` and pass it as a string. Then `deserialize()` it.