# PDO large results

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem with `PDO` returns incomplete result. Specific query executed in phpmyadmin returns 6000 rows. Same query executed by `PDO` returns only first 1160 rows. Seems like some kind of limitation or something. This setting

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

did not help.

Thx for answer

**Edit**

```
SELECT 
T1.`column1`,
MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( T1.`column2` ) ) AS month,
YEAR( FROM_UNIXTIME( T1.`column2` ) ) AS year, 
(SELECT CONCAT(T2.`column1`,';',T2.`column2`,';',T3.`column1`) FROM `table2` T2 WHERE     
T2.`column8` = T1.`column8` AND T2.`column1` LIKE '%new%') AS news,
(SELECT CONCAT(T2.`column1`,';',T2.`column2`,';',T3.`column1`) FROM `table2` T2 WHERE    
T2.`column8` = T1.`column8` AND T2.`column1` LIKE '%old%') AS oldies,
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.column9 = T3.column2
WHERE T1.`column2` > 1388534400
```

It will be one-time execution so optimalization not needed

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: This cannot be the query. There is a syntax error in this query.

Comment: Danke, just typing error when rewriting query here.

Comment: Danke is german ^^ that means thanks :) but how do you know there are 6k entrys selected... and how you see you only get 1160 ? Actually I think you have a to low set `max_input_vars`

Comment: 6k = phpmyadmin, same query PDO while($row = $stmt->fetch()){...} = 1160. PDO can be affected by max_input_vars?

Comment: I had a issue that looked like this... see this accepted answere [POST DATA REDUCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234320/passing-array-via-jquerys-post-reduces-positions). Its about jquery in this case... but in the backend i select with pdo

Comment: and yes, I think this can affect it becase it also takes memory and thats what max_input_vars is about :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try increasing your `max_input_vars` to `10000` in your `php.ini` and see if anything changes.

At the moment it is 1000 i guess and may you run into memory errors.

Comment: Problem is solved. Im not sure if max_input_vars was the problem but I set this parameter to 10000. Really thank you.

Comment: you welcome. And I really wonder why someone downvotes a correct answere :)