# Large $_POST variable get's cut off

Tags: php, post

I'm send a large array via POST to the server but when I output the `$_POST` variable some parameters are cut off

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST , true).'</pre>';
```

It seems the array is always cut off at the same length so if i add elements at the beginning of the array one element at end will get removed.

This happens only on some servers so I guess it's a wrong setting or some server limitations.

The `post_max_size` is always above 64 mb and the post is not even close to that size

How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I'm having the same problem. My php.ini file seems good, and the size of the POST is nowhere near the different max values.

Comment: See the answer from @kay-angevare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question in my search with a similar nature.
If anyone lands on this page, you might want to also check out this answer by Mr. Robinson:

> Try changing max_input_vars as well. More information: . . . .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667018/11787139

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

You can also use ini_set function:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

Comment: This didn't help, user 256MB for both which is more then enough