# $_POST not containing all input data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to post a large form through php using POST method. My form post script has been working fine until now that the `$_POST` array got pretty large.

When i print out file_get_contents`('php://input');` ,all the inputs that are included in the form, are shown. But when i print out `$_POST`, it only gets the first part of the form. I've tried to remove rows and then the `$_POST` method works fine again. As soon as it gets too large, it won't post all data included in the form.

Anyone got any ideas? I've tried to edit `php.ini` and set `post_max_size` to a higher value, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\_POST max array size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807100/post-max-array-size)

Answer (score 4):

By default, in lower versions of PHP(< 5.3.9) the number of `$_POST` variables is limited to 1000. There is no way to change that.

In higher versions you can set [`max_input_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) to whatever number you wish.

If you're below 5.3.9 there are some work-arounds you can do. For example `json_encode` the variables and send them as a single variable. The limit of `$_POST` is set to `8mb` by default but can be changed in the `php.ini` file `post_max_size="whatever_size_you_wish_here"`.

How to increase the number of variables in `$_POST`:

2 options:

- in your `.htaccess` file do `php_value max_input_vars 2000(or whatever)`
- in the file you're working with `ini_set('max_input_vars', 2000);`

Comment: I've tried to edit 'max_input_vars' too in php.ini, but that didn't help either. My current php version is 5.6.9

Comment: @user2994294 Do `var_dump(count($_POST, COUNT_RECURSIVE))` and see how many you have. Might as well see where you stand to begin with.

Comment: Got the output int(1165)

Comment: Alright so more than 1000. Lemme have a look at the documentation and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @user2994294 Have a look at the edit I've made to my answer. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try dumping a phpinfo() and look for max_input_vars. If it's there, you can set it in php.ini to a higher number, as you see fit. If you don't see it, it's likely that you didn't receive that exact patch and the number has been hard-coded by your distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it, apparently my server didn't update max_input_vars for some strange reason. Now that i increased that value it's working.

Comment: consider accepting an answer so people can reference this in future similar cases.